# How to find (your) posts containing images

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

The title is basically self-explanatory.

I had come up with something on the [query site](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/), but to call it slow was an insult to sloth-kind.  (Something about combining multiple `like` statements on the full text of `Posts.Body` should have seemed like a bad idea, but I forged ahead in error.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Posts.Body` field in SEDE actually contains the rendered HTML version of the post content, so it's pretty easy to [search it for `<img>` tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/303915/find-posts-of-yours-that-include-an-image):

```sql
SELECT Id AS [Post Link]
FROM Posts
WHERE lower(Body) LIKE '%<img%'
AND OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
```

<sup>(Forked from Roombatron5000's query.)</sup>

This query works also for images that are not hosted on imgur.  For example, [running it on my own posts at Meta.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/303915/find-posts-of-yours-that-include-an-image?UserId=174699), it also finds [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212745/why-does-the-cw-hat-the-stallman-look-like-jesus/212756#212756) that uses images directly from Wikimedia Commons.

Answer (score 17):

Well, most images that I see are all hosted by imgur. So I just did a query that searches for your posts that include text like imgur. You can see the query here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/303727/find-posts-of-yours-that-include-an-image?PutYourUserIdHere=272287

Comment: That's because network image hosting is provided by Imgur.